# Merge request for my two accounts

Tags: support, status-completed

I would like to ask you to merge https://cooking.stackexchange.com/users/4044/johannes-schaub-litb into https://cooking.stackexchange.com/users/6538/johannes-schaub-litb .

That is, the older account into the newer, so that in the end, I only have my newer account (I change the open-id to use my google open-id).

Thanks!

Similar to my request for [merging for my tex.stackexchange.com account](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1293/please-merge-these-two-accounts) that happened some times ago.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I've merged the accounts.

FYI, for anyone else who stumbles on this, it's preferable if you update the profile of both accounts to include the merge request so that we have proof that both accounts are really yours. (although in this case it was sort of obvious)

Comment: waiting 8 seconds so I can accept this... [done!] Thanks! :)